# The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. How can i notify the list?

Tags: android

This is my fragment where I create the listview. When the data changed the listview is not notify. How can I do this? I make the request in viewModel using volley. I receive the next error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes. [in ListView(2131558620, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class pharma.com.pharmaapp.Common.EventsArrayAdapter)]
                                                                            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1582)

```
         public class EventesFragment extends Fragment {
                private final String TAG = EventesFragment.class.getSimpleName();
                private ArrayList<EvenimentType> events = new ArrayList<>();
                private ListView eventsListView;
                private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer;
                public EventsArrayAdapter eventsArrayAdapter;
                private EventsFragmentViewModel eventsFragmentViewModel = new EventsFragmentViewModel();


                @Nullable
                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_events, container, false);
                    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
                    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

                    if(events.size() != 0) {
                        events.clear();
                    }
                    eventsListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView_events);
                    swipeContainer = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer);
                    eventsListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            String name = ((EvenimentType) eventsListView.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getName();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Click " + name);
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SelectedEventActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("Parceable", events.get(position));
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });

                    eventsListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            String name = ((EvenimentType) eventsListView.getAdapter().getItem(position)).getName();
                            return false;
                        }
                    });

                    swipeContainer.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onRefresh() {
                            events.clear();
                            eventsFragmentViewModel.loadEvents(getActivity());
                            eventsFragmentViewModel.setInterface(new EventsFragmentViewModel.EventsFragmentInterface() {
                                @Override
                                public void takeData(ArrayList<EvenimentType> list) {
                                if(eventsArrayAdapter == null) {
                                    eventsArrayAdapter = new EventsArrayAdapter(getActivity(), list);
                                    eventsListView.setAdapter(eventsArrayAdapter);
                                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                                     } else {
                                    events = list;
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            eventsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                        }
                                    });

                                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                                }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });


                    loadEvents();

                    return view;

                }

                public void loadElementsToArrayAdapter() {

                    eventsArrayAdapter = new EventsArrayAdapter(getContext(), events);
                   // eventsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    swipeContainer.setRefreshing(false);
                    eventsListView.setAdapter(eventsArrayAdapter);
                    eventsFragmentViewModel.saveEvents(events, getActivity());

                }

                public void loadEvents() {
                    eventsFragmentViewModel.loadEvents(getActivity());
                    eventsFragmentViewModel.setInterface(new EventsFragmentViewModel.EventsFragmentInterface() {
                        @Override
                        public void takeData(ArrayList<EvenimentType> list) {
                            events = list;
                            loadElementsToArrayAdapter();

                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onResume() {
                    super.onResume();
                  //  eventsFragmentViewModel.getUserEventsId(getActivity());
                }


            }


    This is the Base Adapter class:  

    public class EventsArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private static final String TAG = EventsArrayAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
        private Context context;
        private List<EvenimentType> list = null;


        public EventsArrayAdapter(Context context, List<EvenimentType> objects) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = objects;
        }

        public void addAll(List<EvenimentType> objects) {
            if(list == null) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
            }
            list.addAll(objects);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            if(convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_array_adapter, null);
            }
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_simposion_title);
            TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_simposion_date);
            TextView location = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_simposion_location);
            TextView price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_simposion_price);
            ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_event);
            Log.d(TAG, "Checking: " + checkEvent(list.get(position)));
            if (checkSelection(list.get(position)) == true) {
                title.setText(list.get(position).getName());
                date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
                location.setText(list.get(position).getLocation());
                price.setText(list.get(position).getPaid());
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_simposions);

            } else {
                title.setText(list.get(position).getName());
                date.setText(list.get(position).getDate());
                location.setText(list.get(position).getLocation());
                price.setText(list.get(position).getPaid());
            }


            Log.d(TAG, "getView");

            return convertView;
        }


This is the viewModel where I make the request

public class EventsFragmentViewModel extends LoginViewModel {
    private static final String TAG = EventsFragmentViewModel.class.getSimpleName();
    private ArrayList<EvenimentType> events = new ArrayList<>();
    EventsFragmentInterface listener = null;

    public void loadEvents(final Context context) {
                DataServices dataServices = new DataServices(context);
                dataServices.getEvents();
                dataServices.setCommunicationInterface(new RequestToServer.CommunicationInterface() {
                    @Override
                    public void takeResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                            EvenimentType evenimentType = new EvenimentType();
                            JSONArray obj = response.getJSONArray("entry");
                            Log.d(TAG, obj.length() + "");
                            for (int i = 0; i < obj.length(); i++) {
                                events.add(evenimentType.createEvent(obj.getJSONObject(i)));
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                Log.d(TAG, "EVENTS: " + events.size());

                if(listener!= null) {
                    listener.takeData(events);
                }

            }

        });


    }

    public void saveEvents(ArrayList<EvenimentType> list, Context context) {
        Preferences preferences = new Preferences(context);
        preferences.saveToSharedPreferencesEvents(list);
        preferences.getFromSharedPreferencesEvents();
    }

    public void setInterface(EventsFragmentInterface listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

   public interface EventsFragmentInterface {
        public void takeData(ArrayList<EvenimentType> list);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well for what I can see your code is a bit messy, you are re setting the adapter every time you refresh the list. Instead, you should init the adapter just once (inside onCreate) and then just update the contents of `eventsListView` and call `eventsArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` whenever you wanna update the list.

Comment: I set it if the adapter is null